# code works when isolated in JSFiddle but gives error when in site

Tags: javascript, jquery

I literally copied my code into JS Fiddle and it started working fine. No errors.

I am trying to replace certain words with unicode symbols if an @supports query evaluates to true. How I check if it evaluates to true is by checking if a style only it could write has been applied.

The error that I am getting is

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined
```

but I am getting no errors when I use this exact code in JS Fiddle with the same assets.

Here is the link to the JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VJm6r/

Here is the code:

```
if(document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.zIndex === 0){
//ligatures and @supports supported
}
else{
   //ligatures and @supports not supported
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var map = {
        "About": { regex: /About/g, replacement: "&#xe00f" },
        "Work": { regex: /Work/g, replacement: "&#xe010" },
        "CV": { regex: /CV/g, replacement: "&#xe00c" },
        "Resume": { regex: /Resume/g, replacement: "&#xe00e" },
        "down": { regex: /down/g, replacement: "&#xe00d" },
        "Mail": { regex: /Mail/g, replacement: "&#xe011" },
        "Dribbble": { regex: /Dribbble/g, replacement: "&#xe015" },
        "Facebook": { regex: /Facebook/g, replacement: "&#xe013" },
        "GooglePlus": { regex: /GooglePlus/g, replacement: "&#xe012" },
        "Twitter": { regex: /Twitter/g, replacement: "&#xe014" }
    }
    $('.nav a').each(function () {
        var obj = $(this);
        var html = $(this).html();
        obj.html(html.replace(map[html].regex, map[html].replacement));
    });
});
}
```

Comment: Check for jquery version. If its correct, the paste your complete HTML

Comment: Is this ran in an onload in your code? in jsfiddle it's running on window load.

Comment: @hop same jQuery version. `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="assets/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"><\/script>')</script>`

Comment: @KevinB There is a `$(document).ready(function(){ }` in my code above.

Comment: @IrfanMir Yes, but it isn't wrapped around the code where you are trying to access the body element. O.o

Comment: @KevinB I did that because that part of the code is vanilla JS and should work without jQuery.

Comment: There is no property `type` you're trying to access in your code sample. Are you sure this is the offending code?

Comment: @Bart Whoops, I meant `style` not type.

Comment: Is the code loaded in the same place as the fiddle? The fiddle uses the `window.onload` event. If your code is placed in the head `<body>` will not exist when the code executes.

Comment: @Bart what do you mean by ' head `<body` '. It is in the `<head>`

Comment: See @bfavaretto. Placing it in the `<head>` causes the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wait until after the `body` element has been created.  `getElementsByTagName("body")` is returning an empty HTML collection.  `[0]` is returning undefined, which has no `style` property.  You can wrap everything in `$(document).ready` or move it to the bottom of the page.  You could move it after the `<body>` tag, strictly speaking, but one of the first two options is more common practice.

Your jsFiddle is wrapping everything in a `$(window).load`, which is why it works there.

Comment: Thank you, I put the code in a `window.onload = function(){ }` and it works.

Comment: If you do that, there is no point in calling `$(document).ready` inside it.  Since window.load happens after it, everything will be ready.

Comment: I removed the one inside of it, too.

Answer (score 3):

If your code is in the `<head>`,  `document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]` will return undefined, because the body has not been parsed yet. Suggested fix: move your whole script to the end of the body (right before `</body>`).

Comment: or putting it in a `window.onload = function(){ }` I just tried that and it works. What is wrong with using that?

Comment: Irfan, sorry, I missed your comment hen you posted it. Nothing wrong with window.onload, it's a valid solution too (you may notice a longer delay before the code runs, since onload will wait for all assets to load, including images).

Answer (score 1):

The javascript is running while the page is still loading.  The body hasn't had a chance to load yet when the line `document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]` runs so its return `undefined` since nothing is found.  You instead need to move your code to the bottom of the document after the body, or run it after the page has loaded with jQuery and `$(document).ready(function() {/*MY CODE HERE */};`